# Why 0.2 is not equal to 0.2 when using the decimal method?

Tags: python, precision

I am still a beginner at Python, and using the in-built decimal method in Python, it's "slightly" off.

Here's the code:

```
import decimal
print(decimal.Decimal(0.02))
```

And here's the output:

```
0.0200000000000000004163336342344337026588618755340576171875
```

I begin to wonder, how is this possible? `0.02` is not `0.0200000000000000004163336342344337026588618755340576171875`, but the `decimal` module perceives `0.02` as `0.0200000000000000004163336342344337026588618755340576171875`. Is the decimal module bugged, or am I doing something wrong?

Comment: floating point precision

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The `Decimal` method can't do anything if your input is already a float, it won't round it.

The only way for `Decimal` to not do that, it needs a string:

```
print(decimal.Decimal("0.02"))
```

Answer (score 2):

The **decimal** module implements fixed and floating point arithmetic using the model familiar to most people, rather than the IEEE floating point version implemented by most computer hardware. A **Decimal** instance can represent any number exactly, round up or down, and apply a limit to the number of significant digits.

**Decimal** values are represented as instances of the **Decimal** class. ***The constructor takes as argument an integer, or a string. Floating point numbers must be converted to a string before being used to create a Decimal***, letting the caller explicitly deal with the number of digits for values that cannot be expressed exactly using hardware floating point representations.

So, in your case, please pass the string as an input for your **Decimal** method. Hope this helps.

```
import decimal

print(decimal.Decimal('0.02'))
```

[Check the documentation here](https://docs.python.org/3/library/decimal.html)

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-ask).